# Getting an event for aggregator message group expiry with Spring Integration DSL?

Tags: spring-integration

I have an aggregator configured via the Java DSL in a Spring Integration flow, and I want to throw an exception that goes to the global error channel when a group timeout occurs.

The discard channel is no good for me because discard messages are at the group member level, rather than for the whole group.

I've tried using the application event publisher as follows, but the publisher object doesn't seem to get invoked:

```
            .aggregate(new Consumer<AggregatorSpec>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(AggregatorSpec aggregatorSpec) {
                    try {
                        aggregatorSpec
                        .outputProcessor(groupPublishStrategy())
                        .correlationStrategy(groupPublishStrategy())
                        .releaseStrategy(groupPublishStrategy())
                        .groupTimeout(groupTimeout)
                        .get().getT2().setApplicationEventPublisher(myGroupExpirationPublisher());
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            })
```

Is there a recommended way to get notification for this use case?  Any ideas why the above doesn't seem to work?

I suppose I could extend the `AggregatorSpec` class to get the message handler configured the way I want, but I wanted to see if I could do this with stock SI classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have just tested and `ApplicationEventPublisher` is populated properly on the bean initialization phase.

The `expireGroup(Object correlationKey, MessageGroup group)` is enough big to demonstrate it here, but you can find its code on [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/aggregator/AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java#L624). So, `MessageGroupExpiredEvent` is always published when we reach this method.
Of course if `discardMessage(message);` doesn't throw exception.

OTOH the `exprireGroup()` is reachable only in this case:

```
if (this.releaseStrategy.canRelease(groupNow)) {
    completeGroup(correlationKey, groupNow);
}
else {
    expireGroup(correlationKey, groupNow);
}
```

So, please, be sure that your `groupPublishStrategy()` has proper logic and doesn't return `true` when your group isn't completed yet.

Well, it really would be better if you debug `AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler` for your use-case. If you are sure that your group isn't completed during some `groupTimeout`, the `forceComplete(MessageGroup group)` is a good place for you to start debugging.

Otherwise, please, share `DEBUG` logs for the `org.springframework.integration` category, when you think that an event has to be emitted.

Comment: Ha..debugging is what I have been doing!  I knew that expireGroup was already being called because I was seeing the "Expire MessageGroup" log message, so there's no problem with group expiry.  But what is happeing is that my ApplicationEventPublisher is being replaced by an instance of AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext somewhere along the way, so the expiration is being published to that object instead of mine.

Comment: OK! That changes everything. You would like to replace a default `ApplicationEventPublisher` with your own and that doesn't work for you. Well, how about to follow with standard flow and just listen for the `MessageGroupExpiredEvent` s, e.g. using SI `ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer` with the `errorChannel` as a output from there?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I had gotten as far as turning my `ApplicationEventPublisher` into an `ApplicationListener<MessageGroupExpiredEvent>`, but hadn't found `ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer` yet.  That appears to be what I need.  I'll test it out and report back, thanks!

Comment: Looks here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/applicationevent.html. You need `spring-integration-event` dependency.

Comment: Artem, I played around with the ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer, but since the goal is just to report expirations as errors, and the Spring Integration default error channel automatically receives all background exceptions, I instead decided to define an extension of `ApplicationListener<MessageGroupExpiredEvent>` that throws an `IllegalStateException` when an event is received.

Comment: Well, it's your choice, but you should be sure that you are async there for errorChannel: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler